# Searching a file, multiple occurrences

Tags: c#

The code I have only shows the first occurrence of the searched string, I would like to show every occurrence, does anyone know how I can do this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string yearInput ; // User input
    // User input

    string[] Year = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Year.txt");
    string[] Month = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Month.txt");
    string[] Rain = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\WS1_Rain.txt");

    Console.Write("Enter a Year: ");
    yearInput = Console.ReadLine();

    var yearIndex = Array.FindIndex(Year, year => year == yearInput);

    var outputMonth = Month[yearIndex];// The corresponding Month for the input
    var outputRain = Rain[yearIndex]; // The corresponding rain for the input

    Console.WriteLine("Year:{0}    Month:{1}       Rain:{2}     ",yearInput ,outputMonth, outputRain );
}
}
```

Comment: But your lines contain also other text or just the year/moth/rain value? And it is not clear what is the relationship between the year file and month/rain file

Comment: In the files? They only only contain the values ( 1 on each line)

Comment: There's an overload of `Array.FindIndex` that takes a start index.  You can use that to start searching for the next one after the previous one you found in a loop.

Comment: Really! Could you possibly show me how to implement that loop into my code please?

Comment: Could you, please, show (as *extracts*) `Year.txt`, `Month.txt` and `WS1_Rain.txt` files? And, please, the expected output?

Comment: Dmitry i think i have added what you asked for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use LINQ's `Enumerable.Where` to filter and `Enumerable.Zip` to join all by index:

```
var years = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\Josef\Documents\Weather Data\Year.txt");
var months = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\Josef\Documents\Weather Data\Month.txt");
var rains = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\Josef\Documents\Weather Data\WS1_Rain.txt");

var yearMonthRainInfos = years
    .Zip(months, (y, m) => new { year = y, month = m })
    .Zip(rains, (x, r) => new { x.year, x.month, rain = r })
    .Where(x => x.year == yearInput);

foreach (var ymrInfo in yearMonthRainInfos)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Year:{0}    Month:{1}       Rain:{2}",
        ymrInfo.year, ymrInfo.month, ymrInfo.rain);
}
```

Note that i've used `ReadLines` instead of `ReadAllLines` which doesn't need to read all lines into memory before it can start processing.

---

If you want to *"make a message appear if the year they search doesn't exist in that file"* it would be good to store the query result in a collection, then it must be executed only once. Therefore you can use `ToList` or `ToArray`:

```
var yearMonthRainList = years
    .Zip(months, (y, m) => new { year = y, month = m })
    .Zip(rains, (x, r) => new { x.year, x.month, rain = r })
    .Where(x => x.year == yearInput)
    .ToList();
if (yearMonthRainList.Count == 0)  // or yearMonthRainList.Any()
{
    MessageBox.Show("The year " + yearInput + "was not found");
}
else
{
    foreach (var ymrInfo in yearMonthRainList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Year:{0}    Month:{1}       Rain:{2}",
            ymrInfo.year, ymrInfo.month, ymrInfo.rain);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to make a message appear if the year they search doesn't exist in that file?

Comment: @Jermaneeeee: sure, you could use `yearMonthRainInfos.ToList()` to get a list, store it in a variable. Then you can check if it's `Count` property is `> 0`.

Comment: im so sorry to keep bothering you, but for some reason im struggling on how to actually implement what you've told me......so sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Linq to get all the indexes

```
var matchingYearIndexes = Year.Select((y,i) => new { Year=y, Index=i})
                              .Where(x => x.Year == yearInput)
                              .Select(x => x.Index);
```

Then just loop over that to get the corresponding month and rain fall

```
foreach(ver index in matchingYearIndexes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Year:{0}    Month:{1}       Rain:{2}     ",
        yearInput,
        Month[index], 
        Rain[index]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

put a break point after

```
var yearIndex = Array.FindIndex(Year, year => year == yearInput);
```

and check the value of yearIndex 
if that is a integer, u should get 1 record.

if that is an array of integers, u need to loop

Comment: `Array.FindIndex` return an `int`, never an array.